# Extjs add multiple records in the store

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

In my ExtJs app I have to save, after made some editing, multiple records in the store (as many records as it is the number of beaconsCounter) and after reload the store and close the dialog, but I don't know why, nothing happens.
I am a newbie in Extjs so I don't know what it is incorrect in my code.

```js
onSaveClick: function (button) {
              var dialog, store, beaconToSave , window;
              var numberOfBeaconPositionated, beaconsCounter, name, uuid, major, minor, originalNameValue;
              var arrayOfLong, arrayOfLat, nameString;

              window = button.up('window')
              dialog = window.down('form');
              dialog.updateRecord();
              beaconToSave = dialog.getRecord();
              store = beaconToSave.store;

              numberOfBeaconPositionated = this.lookupReference('beaconNumbers').getValue();
              name = beaconToSave.get('name');
              uuid = beaconToSave.get('uuid');
              major = beaconToSave.get('major');
              minor = beaconToSave.get('minor');
              latitude = this.lookupReference('beaconLatitude').getValue();
              longitude = this.lookupReference('beaconLongitude').getValue();

              if((name === "")||(uuid === "")){
                   Ext.Msg.alert(Strings.errorTitle, Strings.errorFieldMissing, Ext.emptyFn);
              }else if ((major === 0)||(minor === 0)){
                   Ext.Msg.alert(Strings.errorTitle, Strings.errorMajMin, Ext.emptyFn);
              }else if((longitude === "0")||(latitude === "0")){
                   Ext.Msg.alert(Strings.errorTitle, Strings.errorNoBeacons, Ext.emptyFn);
              }else{
                  nameString = name.split("-");

                  if((name.indexOf('-%min%') >= 0) || (name.indexOf('-%maj%') >= 0) || (name.indexOf('-'+major+'-'+minor) >= 0) || (nameString[1]!=null)) {
                     originalNameValue=nameString[0];
                  }else{
                     originalNameValue = name;
                  }

                  uuid = beaconToSave.get('uuid');
                  major = beaconToSave.get('major');
                  minor = beaconToSave.get('minor');
                  latitude = this.lookupReference('beaconLatitude').getValue();
                  longitude = this.lookupReference('beaconLongitude').getValue();
                  arrayOfLong = longitude.split(",");
                  arrayOfLat = latitude.split(",");
                  store = beaconToSave.store;
                  beaconsCounter = numberOfBeaconPositionated;

                  while(beaconsCounter > 0 ){

                      newRecord = beaconToSave.copy();
                      name=originalNameValue.concat("-"+major+"-"+minor);
                      newRecord.set('name',name);
                      newRecord.set('latitude',arrayOfLat[beaconsCounter-1]);
                      newRecord.set('longitude',arrayOfLong[beaconsCounter-1]);
                      newRecord.set('minor',minor);


                       if ( !store && !Ext.isEmpty(savedStore)){
                                 store = savedStore;
                             }
                             if (store) {
                                 if (newRecord.phantom) {
                                     store.add(newRecord);
                                 }
                                 store.sync({
                                     failure: function (batch) {
                                         store.rejectChanges();
                                         savedStore = store;
                                         if ( batch.exceptions[0].getError().status){
                                             if ( batch.exceptions[0].getError().status == 409){
                                                 Traccar.app.showError(this.getTitle() + Strings.errorAddDuplicate);
                                             }else if(batch.exceptions[0].getError().status == 400){
                                                 Traccar.app.showError(this.getTitle() + Strings.errorAddDatabase);
                                             }else{
                                                 Traccar.app.showError(batch.exceptions[0].getError().response);
                                             }
                                         }

                                     },
                                     success: function(){
                                         store.reload();
                                         this.close();
                                     }, scope: window
                                 });
                             } else {
                                 newRecord.save();
                                 this.closeView();
                             }
                      minor++;
                      beaconsCounter--;
                  }

              }
     },
```

Comment: How is store defined? Can you attach the define/create code?

Comment: `Ext.define('Traccar.view.dialog.BeaconController', {
    extend: 'Traccar.view.dialog.BaseEditController',
    alias: 'controller.beacon',

    requires: [
        'Traccar.view.BaseWindow',
        'Traccar.view.map.LocationSelectionMap'
    ],`

Comment: You attached the controller code instead of store. Please attach correct code.

Comment: ah ok, sorry, do you mean this? :  `Ext.define('Traccar.store.Beacons', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Traccar.model.Beacon',

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        api: {
            create  : 'api/beacons',
            read    : 'api/beacons',
            update  : 'api/beacons',
            destroy : 'api/beacons'
        },
        writer: {
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
});`

Comment: "Nothing happens" mean no update/create invoked ? View isn't closed? Record has been added to store?

Comment: exactly, the records are not stored and the view doesn't close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `newRecord = beaconToSave.copy()` because this make new record with same id. Use newRecord = `{'name':name,'latitude':arrayOfLat[beaconsCounter-1],'longitude',arrayOfLong[beaconsCounter-1],'minor',minor};` instead